# Two struct one function

Tags: c, avr

I would like to do in C code something like that to call one function with can operate on two similar but not the same struct. Now I have two function that do the same but different type data.
I can't change struct to the same data type. The struct must have different data type.
I tried by void pointer but doesn't work. Dynamic cast pointer but I don't think it's possible in C code. I can't use allocate memory dynamically malloc etc.
It is possible to implement?

```
    typedef struct st1_tag
    {
        uint32_t a;
        uint16_t b;
        uint16_t tab[10];
    }st1_t;

    typedef struct st2_tag
    {
        uint8_t a;
        uint16_t b;
        uint32_t tab[10];
    }st2_t;

...
    
    st1_t x1;
    st2_t x2;

...

void foo_1(void)
{
    if(x1.b > 2)
    {
        //to do someting on data struct x1
    }
}

void foo_2(void)
{
    if(x2.b > 2)
    {
        //to do something similar like in foo1 but data type field of struct are not the same.
    }
}

void foo3(void)
{
    foo1();
    foo2();
}
```

Comment: Use a `union` type.

Comment: _"I tried by void pointer but doesn't work."_.   In what way did this not work?

Comment: `x1.b` and `x2.b` are of the same data type `uint16_t`, so you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj - I cannot say for sure, but I believe using `x1.b > 2` was just an unintended and unfortunate choice for an example.  The other members in the two `struct` definitions are not the same, and would perhaps therefore require different treatment.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I tried by void pointer but doesn't work."*.

And:

> *"I can't use allocate memory dynamically malloc"*

I am not sure in what  way using `void *` did not work, but the following defines one function, that can be used to convey either type of struct via `void *`, without using dynamic allocation:

```
  typedef struct st1_tag
    {
        uint32_t a;
        uint16_t b;
        uint16_t tab[10];
    }st1_t;
    st1_t s1, *pS1;   

    typedef struct st2_tag
    {
        uint8_t a;
        uint16_t b;
        uint32_t tab[10];
    }st2_t;
    st2_t s2, *pS2;
    
    typedef enum {
        TYPE_1,
        TYPE_2,
        TYPE_MAX
    }type_e;


void operate_on_two_different_struct(void *s, type_e type);   
    
int main()
{
    st1_t st1 = {18, 25, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}};
    st2_t st2 = {10, 25000, {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100}};    
    
    operate_on_two_different_struct(&st1, TYPE_1);
    operate_on_two_different_struct(&st2, TYPE_2);
    
    return 0;
}

void operate_on_two_different_struct(void *s, type_e type)
{
    switch(type) {//demonstrates conveyance of data, nothing else.
        case TYPE_1:                
            pS1= (st1_t *)s;
            break;
        case TYPE_2:
            pS2 = (st2_t *)s;
            break;
    }
}
```

If you need more specificity than this, or some other information, post a comment under.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I didn't mention it is code on microcontroller AVR and I have to save the memory. Originally those struct take almost half memory.

Comment: @szkarbun - yes, that would have been good to know.

Comment: @szkarbun - re-wrote answer based on your comments here, and in your post.

Comment: Than you very much. This is what I meant, a long way ahead of me. By the way it's possible to get access by one pointer to two different struct as above?

Comment: @szkarbun - can you be more specific? I believe the only pointer that can be used to reference multiple different `types` of objects is a void *, but I have my suspicions that you are needing something else?

Comment: @szkarbun - It appears you are trying to use `void *` as a pointer to object, but they cannot be applied that way.   Nor can a `void *` be dereferenced.  Read [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/void-pointer-c-cpp/).

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not described very well by the `struct` feature of the C language so maybe just don't use that feature.  You can write a function that reads and writes data to your structs using a simple byte pointer of type `uint8_t *`.  The function needs some way to figure out the offset of `b`, so you can provide that using a second argument or something.

```c
void foo_1(uint8_t * ptr)
{
    uint8_t b_offset = ...;
    if(ptr[b_offset] > 2)
    {
      // Now do something to data.  Here are some examples:

      // read and write data as bytes
      ptr[13] = ptr[12] + 7;

      // read and write data as uint16_t
      *(uint16_t *)(ptr + 13) = *(uint16_t *)(ptr + 12) + 7;
    }
}
```